# How do I resolve the “Inner matrix dimensions must agree” error?

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, convex-optimization, cvx

This is my code in `CVX`:

```
load('C')

r=C(:,4);
t=C(:,5);

n = size(C,1);
N = 100;

for i=1:n
    eta(i,1) = randn()/2;
end

cvx_begin
    variable x(n,1)

    maximize r'*x - t'*x

    subject to
        ones(n,1)'*x == N
        x >= zeros(n,1)
        exp(-x/N) >= eta
cvx_end
```

It gives the following error in the line where the objective function is declared:

> “Inner matrix dimensions must agree.”

What am I doing wrong?

The error persists even if I write the last constraint as follows:

```
for i=1:n
    exp(-x(i,1)/N) >= eta(i,1)
end
```

Comment: Yes, since `r`, `x` and `t` all are `n x 1` vectors, `r'*x - t'*x` should be a scalar.

Comment: Wait you modified the error message. in which line is the error happening?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes, I just figured out why the `objective function is not scalar` error was showing. It was because when declaring the variable `x`, I should have declared it as `x(n,1)`, otherwise, as you said, `CVX` would think it is a scalar if I simply declare it as `x`. So now that's fixed, but I have a different error, which is what I have edited the question to reflect.

Comment: @AnderBiguri In the line `maximize r'*x - t'*x`.

Comment: My guess is the same: cvx does not know the size of t and r

Comment: But I have defined `t` and `r` at the beginning itself as vectors whose dimensions are `n x 1`

Comment: @AnderBiguri Got the error. Need to put parentheses around the objective function, which is required because it has 2 terms: `maximize (r'*x-t'*x)`

Comment: Answer your own question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that I did not put parentheses around the objective function, which is required in this particular case as it has 2 terms. So, `maximize (r'*x-t'*x)` solves the error.